# How do I make dynamically created link buttons behave as check boxes?

Tags: c#, linkbutton

I have a set of link buttons(with an image on it) being dynamically created by a function called in the Page_Load.
What I'm trying to do is make them function as checkboxes. I want a different image to be displayed on the linkbutton on clicking and I want it to change back when clicked again.
I've somehow managed to it with the help of a static variable but it's not functioning properly.Please check the code below:

```
static int enable = 1; //Global variable

 private void binding_function() //Called in Page Load
  {
       LinkButton lnkmod = new LinkButton();
       lnkmod.ID = "lnkmod" + UID; //UID comes from the database.
       lnkmod.CommandName = UID;
       lnkmod.Text = "<i class='btn fa fa-plus-square-o' aria-hidden = 
             'true'><img src='http://localhost:3162/images/moderator-
              red.gif'></i>";

       lnkmod.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lnkmod_com);
       plcUserReq.Controls.Add(lnkmod);
  }
  private void lnkmod_com(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
  {
    string uid = e.CommandName;
    if (enable == 1)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        btn.Text = "<i class='btn fa fa-check-square-o' aria-hidden = 
        'true'><img src='http://localhost:3162/images/moderator-blue.gif'>
        </i>";

        btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        enable = 0;
        return;
    }
    else if(enable==0)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        btn.Text = "<i class='btn fa fa-plus-square-o' aria-hidden = 'true'>
        <img src='http://localhost:3162/images/moderator-red.gif'></i>";

        btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        enable = 1;
        return;
    }
}
```

As I'm taking a static, flag variable, it does not function properly for multiple linkbuttons.
How do I assign a flag variable kinda thing for every individual control so that it keeps switching between the images on click?
Answer might be Viewstate or Session state. But I don't know how to implement it in this context.
Please help!

Comment: if you want checkboxes, why not use checkboxes and style them to look like linkbuttons? Appearance is generally easier to fake than functionality.

Comment: @ADyson I have tried using checkboxes. Problem with that was the Command event handler linked to it was not being fired.
    newcheck.CheckedChanged += new CommandEventHandler(lnkmod_com); >>>>>>(I'm using command event handler as I want to send a command argument as well)

Comment: ok but TBH it would be easier (and faster for user experience) to handle the checkbox "change" event client-side using javascript and swap the image over that way, instead of initiating a full postback just to do that. Not many modern web apps will do full postbacks if they can possibly avoid it. All you seem to be doing is altering some HTML, which is exactly what Javascript is designed for.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense! 
But, I'm not sure how do I implement it...Checkboxes are being dynamically created...(Sorry, new to Javascript)